# kernel library to help in windows driver development

Tags: windows, kernel, driver, linux-device-driver

I'm looking for open-sourced kernel-level helper library.

Instead of roll-my-own data-structures and helper functions - Is there some 
library that ment to be used in kernel mode driver development?

Or is it that every driver developer create such data handling techniques from scratch?

Thanks,
  mordy,

Doing my first step in kernel mode development but lazy...

Comment: It is widely encouraged to copy shamelessly from other known working code, with a brief note in the comments on what you derived your driver from.

Answer (score 1):

Windows kernel driver library by default provides single and linked list as described here, [Singly and Doubly Linked Lists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff563802%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Other than that there aren't any standard libraries for other complex data strucctures. You will have to implement your own.